# pandas shifting missing months

Tags: python, pandas, shift

let's assume the following dataframe and shift operation:

```
d = {'col1': ['2022-01-01','2022-02-01','2022-03-01','2022-05-01'], 'col2': [1,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['shifted'] = df['col2'].shift(1, fill_value=0)
```

I want to create a column containing the values of the month before and filling it up for months which do not exist with 0, so the desired result would look like:

| col1 | col2 | shifted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-05-01 | 4 | 0 |

So in the last line the value is 0 because there is no data for April.

But at the moment it looks like this:

| col1 | col2 | shifted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-02-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-05-01 | 4 | 3 |

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is create month `PeriodIndex`, so possible shift by months, last replace missing values:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['col1']).dt.to_period('m'))
df['shifted'] = df['col2'].shift(1, freq='m').reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)

print (df)
               col1  col2  shifted
col1                              
2022-01  2022-01-01     1        0
2022-02  2022-02-01     2        1
2022-03  2022-03-01     3        2
2022-05  2022-05-01     4        0
```

Last is possible remove PeriodIndex:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
         col1  col2  shifted
0  2022-01-01     1        0
1  2022-02-01     2        1
2  2022-03-01     3        2
3  2022-05-01     4        0
```